# TextBlock Text binding not updating with PropertyChangedEventHandler

Tags: wpf, binding, textblock

I have a StatusLogger class that I want to use through out my entire project to log messages into a TextBlock. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to properly bind it to the TextBlock because some parts of my class are static.

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Name="LogTextBlock" Foreground="Silver"
           Text="{Binding Path=LogText}"
           Height="480" Width="588" Margin="10,10,0,0"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

StatusLogger Class:

```
public class StatusLogger : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Fields

    private static StringBuilder _logText = new StringBuilder();

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string LogText
    {
        get { return _logText.ToString(); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public static void WriteLine(string text, params object[] args)
    {
        _logText.AppendFormat(text + Environment.NewLine, args);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Property Change Handler

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So when I call my StatusLogger.WriteLine within the first method/class that I use it, the messages actually post. My issue is I can't figure out how to continually use StatusLogger.WriteLine in other methods and classes and have the PropertyChangedEventHandler pick it up. <s>because I believe the static WriteLine is making a new instance of StatusLogger?</s>

I feel like this is being done wrong as well under the start up of my MainWindow. Can I set the DateContext to my StatusLogger class in WPF?:

```
private readonly StatusLogger _statusLogger = new StatusLogger();
LogTextBlock.DataContext = _statusLogger;
```

Any suggestions or a better way to go at this?

Answer (score 0):

> the static WriteLine is make a new instance of StatusLogger?

No, it doesn't make a new instance.  And actually, it wouldn't matter even if it did, because `_logText` is static and therefore shared across all instances of `StatusLogger`.

What you need is to raise a property changed event, when you add text, in order to cue the UI to update.  So add to `WriteLine`:

```
public static void WriteLine(string text, params object[] args)
{
    _logText.AppendFormat(text + Environment.NewLine, args);
    OnPropertyChanged("LogText");
}
```

Comment: I've tried that and it won't work because it's a non static method. If I changed OnPropertyChanged to static I mess up the : INotifyPropertyChanged. In the end I could't get it to work.

Comment: It seems to only post messages on the start up of the application. Once it's sitting there loaded, everything after that is no longer logged.

Comment: So I spent an hour messing with it and the PropertyChanged object is always null. I think that is why the new messages are not being posted.